# Two consecutive identical calls to echo have different output

Tags: vimscript, functions

Question reposted [on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58145963/two-consecutive-identical-calls-to-echo-have-different-output-in-vim-function), where it's receiving more attention.

Given the following function in the `.vimrc` file,

```
fu! MyFun(count)
  echo a:count
  echo a:count
  if a:count > 0
    normal ,
    call MyFun(a:count - 1)
  endif
endf
```

calling `:call MyFun(3)` generates the following output.

```
3
3
2
2
1
1
0
0
```

However, if I define the mapping `nn , :<C-U>execute "call MyFun(" . v:count . ")"<CR>`, then the call to `:call MyFun(3)` generates

```
3
0
2
0
1
0
0
0
```

I do understand that the mapping of `,` makes the `MyFun` function call itself twice (`if a:count > 0`), however I cannot understand how this can cause a different result of the two successive calls to `echo a:count`.

Comment: Doesnt `normal ,` call the function with a count 0 when you do the map version? Id expect to see 33002200110000

Comment: Yes, I expect the same.

Comment: Re: Your flag: mods can't move questions either :-( It's possible in some cases but a SE employee would have to do it manually, and I'd rather not add to their workload. It's fine to just ask it again on Stack Overflow if you really want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is all about screen redraw (see `:h echo-redraw`) in Vim.

Changing `echo` to `echom` still produces the same (broken) screen output (`3 0 2 0 1 0 0 0`), but `:mess` reveals what is hidden: `3 3 0 0 2 2 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it happens, but if you add a `\n` after the `echo` it all works and the result is what you would expect:

```
fu! MyFun(count)
  echo a:count . "\n"
  echo a:count . "\n"
  if a:count > 0
    normal ,
    call MyFun(a:count - 1)
  endif
endf
```

But maybe you already knew that and was just curious to know *why* (as I confess I am).